# Expressions Simplifications Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

**Expressions Simplifications Boolean Algebra**
I started simplifying function and got to the detailed picture and wanted to know if I can reduce the above expressions, for example :

Y'.X'.Y = 0 ?

Y'.X'.Z.X = 0 ?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Both disjunction and conjunction are commutative in a boolean algebra. Hence
$$Y^\prime X^\prime Y = X^\prime YY^\prime=0$$ for instance.

Comment: and YXY will be equal to XY ? because of YY=Y, and Y'Y'=Y' ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you, really helped me